# update one table using data in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

i have table A

```
mem_id | temp_id | version
--------------------------
1      | 1008    | 1
2      | 1009    | 1
3      | 1010    | 1
4      | 1021    | 1
```

and table B

```
temp_id | base id | desc
--------------------------
1008    | 720     | GP
1009    | 720     | GP
1010    | 720     | GP
1021    | 720     | GP
```

I want to do an update statement that will update the `temp_id` for all `mem_id` in table A to only `temp_id = 1008`.

```
update table a
set a.temp_id = (minimum of temp_id in table b)
where a.temp_id in (select temp_id in table b where b.tempid (min)
```

i want it to check for the minimum value in table `b_temp_id` and then set all values in table `A_temp_id` to be the same.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to determine the minimum temp_id in table B. That is 1008. Then you want to update all rows in table A that have that temp_id with that temp_id? `update a set temp_id = 1008 where temp_id = 1008`? That makes no sense. Please show the table A content after the update.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly update by

```
update tableA A
   set temp_id = (select min(temp_id) from tableB)
```

for the whole data set without any restriction

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=25a6648be6c794c186d4847bc21e6ef8)</kbd>

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that I use oracle

Comment: There is no need for a WITH clause. You simply can put it into the subquery https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7ff5d1c3c5b5e2489bd8cd4ed55298e0

Comment: OK I rearranged for Oracle DB

Comment: of course @S-Man , that's the way I like :) anyway, thanks.